# Data load with Teradata TPT failing

Tags: teradata

Here i'm trying load a csv file into teradata tables using TPT utility
,but is filing with an error:

**Here is my TPT script:**

```
DEFINE JOB test_tpt
DESCRIPTION 'Load a Teradata table from a file'
(
DEFINE SCHEMA SCHEMA_EMP_NAME
(
NAME VARCHAR(50),
AGE VARCHAR(50)    
);

DEFINE OPERATOR od_EMP_NAME
TYPE DDL
ATTRIBUTES
(
VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'tpt_log',
VARCHAR LogonMech      = 'LDAP',
VARCHAR TdpId          = 'TeraDev',
VARCHAR UserName       = 'user',
VARCHAR UserPassword   = 'pwd',
VARCHAR ErrorList      = '3807'
);

DEFINE OPERATOR op_EMP_NAME
TYPE DATACONNECTOR PRODUCER
SCHEMA SCHEMA_EMP_NAME
ATTRIBUTES
(
VARCHAR  DirectoryPath= '/home/hadoop/retail/',
VARCHAR  FileName = 'emp_age.csv',
VARCHAR  Format   = 'Delimited',
VARCHAR  OpenMode = 'Read',
VARCHAR  TextDelimiter =','
);


DEFINE OPERATOR ol_EMP_NAME
TYPE LOAD
SCHEMA *
ATTRIBUTES
(
VARCHAR LogonMech           = 'LDAP',
VARCHAR TdpId          = 'TeraDev',
VARCHAR UserName       = 'user',
VARCHAR UserPassword   = 'pwd',
VARCHAR  LogTable     =  'EMP_NAME_LG',
VARCHAR  ErrorTable1  =  'EMP_NAME_ET',
VARCHAR  ErrorTable2  =  'EMP_NAME_UV',
VARCHAR  TargetTable  =  'EMP_NAME'
);

STEP stSetup_Tables
(
APPLY
('DROP TABLE EMP_NAME_LG;'),
('DROP TABLE EMP_NAME_ET;'),
('DROP TABLE EMP_NAME_UV;'),
('DROP TABLE EMP_NAME;'),
('CREATE TABLE EMP_NAME(NAME VARCHAR(50), AGE VARCHAR(2));')
TO OPERATOR (od_EMP_NAME);
);

STEP stLOAD_FILE_NAME
(
APPLY
('INSERT INTO EMP_NAME
(Name,Age)
VALUES
(:Name,:Age);
')
TO OPERATOR (ol_EMP_NAME)
SELECT * FROM OPERATOR(op_EMP_NAME);
);
);
```

**Call TPT:**

```
tbuild -f test_tpt.sql
```

**Above TPT script is failing with following error:**

```
Teradata Parallel Transporter Version 15.10.01.02 64-Bit
TPT_INFRA: Syntax error at or near line 6 of Job Script File 'test_tpt.sql':
TPT_INFRA: At "NAME" missing RPAREN_ in Rule: Explicit Schema Element List
TPT_INFRA: Syntax error at or near line 8 of Job Script File 'test_tpt.sql':
TPT_INFRA: TPT03020: Rule: DEFINE SCHEMA
```

Compilation failed due to errors. Execution Plan was not generated.
Job script compilation failed                                                                .

Am i missing any detail in here?

Answer (score 1):

The messages certainly could be clearer, but the issue is that `NAME` is a restricted word.

Comment: I have passed through the error after changing reserved words, but ended up with this error:: Found CheckPoint file: /opt/teradata/client/15.10/tbuild/checkpoint/hadoopLVCP
TPT_INFRA: TPT02743: Error: Cannot get the current job step from the Checkpoint file.
  The job is terminated.

Comment: Either use twbrmcp command to remove the checkpoint file or add the `-s 1` option to the tbuild command line to clear the checkpoint and start with the first (only) step.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes for columns that are reserved words, for example "Name"